# DeprecationWarning: 'getMutableClone' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use an appropriate `factory.update...` method instead,.. (look inside)

Tags: angular

"..use `setCommentRange` or `setSourceMapRange`, and avoid setting `parent`."
I've just updated my local Angular CLI vers. of my project and now I get this: "DeprecationWarning: 'getMutableClone' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use an appropriate `factory.update...` method instead, use `setCommentRange` or `setSourceMapRange`, and avoid setting `parent`."
How and where can I solve it?

Comment: Depending on your Angular version, you should check that a matching TypeScript dependency is installed. According to https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-14.0 Angular 14 e. g. uses TypeScript 4.6. So you should make sure, your `package.json` asks for an appropriate TypeScript version within `devDependencies` such as `"typescript": "~4.6.4"`.

Answer (score 42):

I had this same problem and I've found that it depends from the new version 4.8 of typescript, I've resolved downgrading it ( add --force if necessary ). This should install typescript 4.7.4

```
npm i typescript@"<4.8"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, downgrading typescript fixed the bug "NG0202: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection" in Jest. I don't know how much this is related...

Answer (score 11):

For me I was upgrading from ng11 to ng12
typescript version was `"^4.3.5"` then I change it to `"~4.3.5"`
works fine for now

Answer (score 1):

The Angular team is [working on this](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/47167). Most of the usages have been removed but this is still a WIP as of `14.2.3`.

This message appeared with the depreciation of `getMutableClone` in TS 4.8, no need to downgrade TS for those who have it as everything works as expected. Angular team is expecting `getMutableClone` to be removed with TS 5.0.